# How to convert a string of russian cyrillic letters?

Tags: java, encoding

I parsing mp3 tags.

`String artist`  - I do not know what was on the encoding

`Ïåñíÿ ïðî íàäåæäó` - example string in russian `"Песня про надежду"`

I use http://code.google.com/p/juniversalchardet/

code:

```
String GetEncoding(String text) throws IOException {
        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];


        InputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes());


        UniversalDetector detector = new UniversalDetector(null);

        int nread;
        while ((nread = fis.read(buf)) > 0 && !detector.isDone()) {
            detector.handleData(buf, 0, nread);
        }
        detector.dataEnd();
        String encoding = detector.getDetectedCharset();
        detector.reset();
        return encoding;
    }
```

And covert

`new String(text.getBytes(encoding), "cp1251");` -but this not work.

if I use utf-16

`new String(text.getBytes("UTF-16"), "cp1251")` return "юя П е с н я п р о н а д е ж д у" space - not is char space

**EDIT:**

this first read bytes

```
byte[] abyFrameData = new byte[iTagSize];
oID3DIS.readFully(abyFrameData);
ByteArrayInputStream oFrameBAIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(abyFrameData);
```

String s = new String(abyFrameData, "????");

Comment: how are you getting the String text parameter?  perhaps the problem has to do with how you're creating the input to the detector.  java Strings are always UTF-16, so there'a already been some character conversion at that point.

Comment: `new String(text.getBytes("UTF-16"), "cp1251")` does not do what you think it does. What it actually does is take an existing string, retrieve its bytes as UTF-16, then attempt to create a new string by pretending that those bytes bytes are CP1251. Which is guaranteed to be wrong.

Comment: @ stevevls , hmmm java Strings are always UTF-16, not Unicode http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/index.html

Comment: Taking a second look, *stevevls* has the right direction: post the code that retrieves `text`. This is where you should be detecting the encoding. What you're actually doing is applying some unknown encoding to turn the file's bytes into a string (unknown because you dodn't paste the code), then some other unknown encoding to turn that string back into bytes (unknown because you don't specify the encoding and we don't know your platform default), then trying to detect the encoding of those bytes.

Comment: **This** is your immediate problem: `GetEncoding(String text)`. There's no reason for you to be converting the `byte[]` to a string just so you can convert it back to bytes to guess the encoding (which is lost by the time you get through those conversions). Change the function to take a `byte[]`.

Comment: **But**, your real problem is that you shouldn't try to guess the encoding. As *McDowell*'s answer says, it should be specified by the file itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java strings are UTF-16. All other encodings can be represented using byte sequences. To decode character data, you must provide the encoding when you first create the string. If you have a corrupted string, it is already too late.

Assuming ID3, the specifications define the rules for encoding. For example, [ID3v2.4.0](http://www.id3.org/id3v2.4.0-structure) might restrict the encodings used via an extended header:

> q - Text encoding restrictions
>
> ```
>    0    No restrictions
>    1    Strings are only encoded with ISO-8859-1 [ISO-8859-1] or
>         UTF-8 [UTF-8].
> ```

Encoding handling is defined further down the document:

> If nothing else is said, strings,
>   including numeric strings and URLs,
>   are represented as ISO-8859-1
>   characters in the range $20 - $FF.
>   Such strings are represented in frame
>   descriptions as `<text string>`, or
>   `<full text string>` if newlines are
>   allowed. If nothing else is said
>   newline character is forbidden. In
>   ISO-8859-1 a newline is represented,
>   when allowed, with $0A only.
>
> Frames that allow different types of
>   text encoding contains a text encoding
>   description byte. Possible encodings:
>
> ```
>  $00   ISO-8859-1 [ISO-8859-1]. Terminated with $00.
>  $01   UTF-16 [UTF-16] encoded Unicode [UNICODE] with BOM. All
>        strings in the same frame SHALL have the same byteorder.
>        Terminated with $00 00.
>  $02   UTF-16BE [UTF-16] encoded Unicode [UNICODE] without BOM.
>        Terminated with $00 00.
>  $03   UTF-8 [UTF-8] encoded Unicode [UNICODE]. Terminated with
>        $00.
> ```

Use transcoding classes like `InputStreamReader` or (more likely in this case) the [`String(byte[],Charset)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) constructor to decode the data. See also [Java: a rough guide to character encoding](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html).

---

Parsing the string components of an ID3v2.4.0 data structure would something like this:

```
//untested code
public String parseID3String(DataInputStream in) throws IOException {
  String[] encodings = { "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-16", "UTF-16BE", "UTF-8" };
  String encoding = encodings[in.read()];
  byte[] terminator =
      encoding.startsWith("UTF-16") ? new byte[2] : new byte[1];
  byte[] buf = terminator.clone();
  ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  do {
    in.readFully(buf);
    buffer.write(buf);
  } while (!Arrays.equals(terminator, buf));
  return new String(buffer.toByteArray(), encoding);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is works for me:

```
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
UniversalDetector encDetector = new UniversalDetector(null);
encDetector.handleData(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
encDetector.dataEnd();
String encoding = encDetector.getDetectedCharset();
if (encoding != null) s = new String(bytes, encoding);
```