# Java - Russian Encoding

Tags: java, cyrillic

I'm trying to print Russian text like the below example but got ? characters.
I have tried multiple "encodings" but the same result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String t = "тест";
        System.out.println("test: " + t);
    }
```

Output: test: ????

How can I do right encoding?

Comment: set character encoding

Comment: I did already (Charset.defaultCharset()) but the same result ?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017004/how-to-convert-a-string-of-russian-cyrillic-letters

Comment: intellij idea, but i think the reason isnt with IDE because im trying to write the text in a file and the same ??????.

Comment: What is your system's default encoding?

Comment: ISO-8859-1, but i changed it to UTF-8

Comment: @RealSkeptic likely CP1251 is Java default encoding, but CP866 is actually used for console output (Windows defaults). Displaying text in Russia is not that easy!

Comment: Just try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream

Comment: Your code works fine here, on a French Mac, in IntelliJ. Make sure the encoding used to compile your sources, in IntelliJ, is UTF8. You should see UTF8 when the source file is opened, at the bottom-right corner of IntelliJ. In the IntelliJ preferences, under Editor - File encodings, make sure the IDE encoding and the project encoding is also UTF8.

Comment: I did it but the same.

Answer (score 3):

The characters that you see couldn't be decoded properly on the device displaying them. It could be many reasons, but the main cause is the device is using another encoding scheme. To properly encode character stream use the following code that writes to the file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    OutputStreamWriter fileWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("myFile.txt"), "windows-1251");

    String t = "тест";
    fileWriter.write("test: " + t);
}
```